# a.s convergence and convergence in probability.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I would like to have a better intuitive feeling concerning the difference between the two modes of convergence. Consider the following example :

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables such that $P(X_n=1) = p_n \rightarrow 0$.

Depending on the speed of convergence of the $p_n$, the sequence will converge a.s. or only in probability. Take $p_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ or $p_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for instance. On one side, the event $\{X_n=1\}$ has positive measure for all $n$ in both cases. On the other side the Borel-Cantelli lemma and the "converse result" (legal since the $X_n$ are independent) can be used to directly prove that the sequence is $0$ a.s. after a certain rank when $p_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$, but infinitely many $1's$ are expected when $p_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

What causes **intuitively** those two different behaviors?

Comment: Series whose terms decline towards zero fast enough have a finite sum, while series whose terms decline too slowly have an infinite sum.

Comment: Sure thing, but this is not my question :/

Comment: But it is the underlying cause of these otherwise counter-intuitive results

Comment: Agreed. It all boils down to the link between the probability of the lim sup of a collection of events, and the serie of the probabilities of those events. Borel-Cantelli is a two line, straightforward, proof... yet I have never had an intuitive feeling for it.